# How to get all values from cache which start with certain key

Tags: php, laravel, caching

As the title, I want to get all values from cache which start with certain value.

For example, I'm counting post views in my project and I'm storing them on cache. Then I want to reach all stored viewed values on cache..

with Session helper, it's separates keys by dot and create multidimensional array.

So can we can get the stored items like `Session::get("views")` it gives all stored items used "views." key.

How we can do same thing with Cache ?

```
function get_all_cache(){
    $filesystem = \Cache::getStore()->getFilesystem();
    $cache_dir = (\Cache::getDirectory());
    $keys = [];
    foreach ($filesystem->allFiles($cache_dir) as $file1) {
        if (is_dir($file1->getPath())) {
            foreach ($filesystem->allFiles($file1->getPath()) as $file2) {
                $keys = array_merge($keys, [$file2->getRealpath() => unserialize(substr(\File::get($file2->getRealpath()), 10))]);
            }
        }
    }
    return $keys;
}
```

Comment: Tingir can u try first?

Comment: @JigneshJoisar I made a solution but not best practise. I put in foreach loop all post ids. But it tooks to long, I'm looking for a more elegant way

Comment: Tingir can u add code which u have practice. so i can help better if possible.

Comment: @JigneshJoisar I edited my question

Answer (score 1):

> not proper answer but i give u my best answer

```
try like this 


function get_all_cache(){
    if(\Cache::has('viewsValue')) {
          $keys =  \Cache::get('viewsValue');
    }else {
    $filesystem = \Cache::getStore()->getFilesystem();
    $cache_dir = (\Cache::getDirectory());
    $keys = [];
    foreach ($filesystem->allFiles($cache_dir) as $file1) {
        if (is_dir($file1->getPath())) {
            foreach ($filesystem->allFiles($file1->getPath()) as $file2) {
                $keys = array_merge($keys, [$file2->getRealpath() => unserialize(substr(\File::get($file2->getRealpath()), 10))]);
            }
        }
    }
    \Cache::put('viewsValue',$keys,60);   ///add key array into cache 
    }

  return $keys;
 }
```

> note first time if key is not exists then store cache values on keys next
>   time always get on cache so better performance
>
> `only work if not updated your keys array every time`

for more cache understanding [see](https://scotch.io/tutorials/caching-in-laravel-with-speed-comparisons)